# Why does WordPress have a noop.php file?

Tags: plugin-development

While configuring Ctags to recognize WordPress functions, I came across the [noop.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/noop.php) file. Here is an excerpt:

```
/**
 * @ignore
 */
function add_action() {}

/**
 * @ignore
 */
function did_action() {}

/**
 * @ignore
 */
function do_action_ref_array() {}
```

**Why does this file exist?** Can I remove it to let VIM better navigate the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description on top of the page you have linked gives an explanation:

> Create a new file, `wp-admin/includes/noop.php`, which loads all of the noop functions for `load-script|styles.php` and is only loaded by those files. DRYs in the process. See [#33813](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33813).

Additionally there is the trac ticket [#33813](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33813) linked, which gives some additional insight. You generally shouldn't delete core files so consider `noop.php` as a necessary file.

Comment: I don't think this or the comment at the top answers the question fully. This answer focuses on why the file exists, but a lot of people will be wondering why a `noop` file with `noop` functions is needed at all. It would be good if a brief explainer of why `noop` functions are needed in core would complete the answer for a lot of people

Answer (score 4):

### Why `noop.php`?

Previously `noop` functions were duplicated across core in multiple places, and an effort was made to co-locate them to avoid this duplication. This was done in https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33813 as part of an organisation effort.

### What Are Noop functions?

Noop, or ***No*** ***Op***-eration functions, are useful for testing and mocking. They're also a way to implement the null pattern, of presenting APIs that don't do anything to act as placeholders for ones that do.

### Can I remove it to let VIM better navigate the code?

**I would not modify core**, instead you should tell ctags to ignore that file. This question/answer on stackoverflow will help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736656/vim-and-ctags-ignoring-certain-files-while-generating-tags